# DataBinding: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a property with the name 'Id'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Can anyone help me I dont know what Iam doing wrong  . . . 
on my controller

```
public ActionResult ProdutoCategoria()
{
    var model = db.Perfies;
    ViewBag.Perfies_Id = new SelectList(db.Perfies.ToList(), "Id", "NomePerfil");  
    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult consultaBD(int id)
{
    var selectedPerfil = (from Perf in db.Perfies
                          where Perf.Id == id
                          select new { Id = Perf.Id, Name = Perf.NomePerfil }).ToList();
    Utilizador utili = db.Utilizadores.Find(id);
    ViewBag.Perfies_Id = selectedPerfil;

    if (utili == null) { 
        return HttpNotFound();  
    }
    return View();
 }
```

on view

```
<form action="/Produto/consultoDB" method="post">
    <label>Select one </label>
    @Html.DropDownList("Perfies_Id", new SelectList(ViewBag.Perfies_Id, "Id", "NomePerfil"))
    <input type="submit" class="button success" value="Enter" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Perfies_Id` is already a `SelectList`. Change the code either in the controller to

```
ViewBag.Perfies_Id = db.Perfies.ToList();
```

or in the view to

```
@Html.DropDownList("Perfies_Id", ViewBag.Perfies_Id)
```

Comment: sorry Zabavsky it doesnt work , I cant put like this @Html.DropDownList("Perfies_Id", ViewBag.Perfies_Id) doesnt show the name of perfil in a combobox and on controller when I put this ViewBag.Perfies_Id = db.Perfies.ToList(); doesnt work as well

Comment: @Zabavsky i think (SelectList) is missing before viewbag in ViewBag.Perfies_Id

Answer (score 1):

Your `select` element name and `ViewBag` variable name for your select list cannot be the same. They will conflict. Change your `ViewBag` variable to something like `ViewBag.Perfies_Id_Choices` and you'll be fine.